# Excel chart with two X-axes (horizontal), possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is it possible to create an Excel chart which has two X-axes (i.e. **horizontal** axes, not vertical Y-axes!) ?

I want to use the second axis to plot the normalized value of the default horizontal axis.
I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/655689/possible-to-have-two-y-axes-and-two-x-axes-on-same-chart

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*[Back at home now, so have rewritten for Excel 2007]*

You can have a "primary" and "secondary" axis in some chart types (line, column and bar at least; maybe others) - they are in pairs so you can't have a secondary x-axis without a secondary y-axis, but you can make the secondary y-axis identical to the primary version, and then hide it, so it has no effect on the graph.

### Instructions:

- Create your basic chart with the required series.
- Right-click the series line for each series that should use the secondary pair of axis, select **Format Data Series**. And inside the **Series Options** tab choose **Secondary Axis**.
- Right-click the chart itself and click **Select Data..**, select on of the series to use the secondary axis and define the **Horizontal (Category) Labels**.
- From the ribbon make the Secondary Axis visible, like so:
  [image: Excel 2007 Ribbon; options to show secondary chart axis]
- Tweak the chart as needed. You may find it useful to use the "more options" option from the image above on the secondary y-axis to ensure it matches your requirements, you can also hide the secondary y-axis, if needed, from the same place.

### Result

Can be something like the below image, should give you an idea of what I'm meaning:
(This is a simple contrived graph I've just thrown together, but should get the point across)
[image: Example chart showing secondary x-axis]

Comment: it is also explained in the official support docs: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-233bc85c-b3db-46c4-87f8-4ffafe2a1080

Answer (score -3):

A 3d column chart will probably do what you need:
[image]

You can set the front columns to be your normalized value and the rear columns to be your other values.  In excel 2007 this is the last one on the right under `3d-Column`.

Let me know if  this doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: A 3D column chart may accommodate the data, but not in a way that makes it at all intelligible. This would most likely be best as an XY Scatter chart, with two series: one using regular X values, the other using normalized X values, and both using the same Y values. After adding the secondary horizontal axis, delete the secondary vertical axis.