# possible to have two Y axes and two X axes on same chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

Is it possible to have a chart with

- left Y axis
- right Y axis
- top X axis
- bottom X axis

all on same chart?

Comment: A chart no, a scatter plot... maybe (not sure about the top X axis though). A better question is why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can have two Y axes on the same graph. Two X axes are not allowed.

Comment: That's not true mehow - see Ale's response below.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/188064/excel-chart-with-two-x-axes-horizontal-possible?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

If I have understand well you have two different datasets to compare on the same chart.

If so

1. You can make your XY chart with both dataset.
2. Then double click on one series, and on the Axis tab, select Secondary. It appears a secondary Y axis.
3. Select "Chart Manu/Chart Options/Axes tab", uncheck the secondary Y box, and check the secondary X box.

[image: Example showing two X and Y axes]

Comment: @Loretta I think you can mark this question as solved